# a SQL aggregation query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an table with 2 columns, a date column and an int column and I want to sum the int columns per month where a month start on the 15th

So the first result would be from today to the 15 of next month (Jan), the next row will be from the 16Jan to the 15Feb and so on until there are no more dates in the first column

Makes sense?

EDITED!!!

Sorry, i'll explain what I mean better.
A month is defined from the 15th of one month to the 14th of the following month.
The first month in the results will be from today to the 14th where the 14th could be a day away or 3 weeks away etc. The second month will be to the 14th of the next month.
The last month in the result will be from the 15th to the end date on the table, so it's possible that the final month could be 2 days of data

Better?

I'll look at the answers now

Comment: Your question is inconsistent about what you mean by the start of the month. If the month starts on the 15th (first paragraph), then the month doesn't go until the 15th of next month (second paragraph). My answer assumes that the 15th is the START of the month, not the END of the month. Hope that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

So you want the month to be considered as the month that is one month later than fourteen days ago. So from today (Dec 17th), we go back 14 days to Dec 3rd, and then add a month to make it Jan 3rd. So today counts as January.

A common method for truncating the month is `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, someDate), 0)`. I'll use that, but first take fourteen days off, and I'll add one when I do the month add.

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(month, 1+DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(day, -14, yourDate)),0) as theMonth, 
    SUM(yourInt) as Total
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY DATEADD(month, 1+DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(day, -14, yourDate)),0);
```

Good luck with this... you may prefer to start with something simple like:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(month, 1+DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(day, -14, yourDate)),0) as theMonth
    , *
FROM yourTable
```

...so that you can understand the logic around the month calculation.

Comment: Just a quick note to explain the truncation method. Every day in December is the same number of months away from a particular point in time (eg, day 0). Adding that number of months back onto day 0 (which is Jan 1, 1900) gives you the start of that date's month. In my query, I'm saying "Add an extra month", so that I get the start of the following month instead. Also, I'm starting 14 days earlier, because you want your months to start on the 15th.

Comment: The expresion dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, datecol-14), 0) will always generate a date of midnight, the first of the month which the date 14 days ago was in...

Comment: Charles - yes, that's correct. I'm just substracting 14 days using DATEADD instead of the integer manipulation that you have. But he wants the following month, which is why I'm adding 1 to the number of months that I add back.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you have to group by an expression that creates buckets defined by the calendar Month

```
  Select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, datecol-14), 0 ) CalendarMonth, 
        sum(col) Total
  From Table
  Group By dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, datecol-14), 0)
```

The expresion  `dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, datecol-14), 0)` will always generate a date of midnight, the first of the month which the date 14 days ago was in...

NOTE: The group by expresion or expressions must be identical to, and include all expressions in the select clause that are not aggregate functions

EDIT:  This expression creates buckets by month, from the 15th through the 14th of the following month, but ***describes*** the buckets using the date of the first of the month the bucket starts in. i.e., It generates a date of the first of the month the start of the bucket is in... for example,  any date from 15 Nov through 14 Dec will give you 1 Nov, any date from 15 Dec through 14 Jan will give you 1 Dec, etc.

Comment: Hi Charles, this works well only that you do: "creates buckets defined by the calendar Month". Can you change it so that a month starts on the 15th and end on the 14th as in my edited question above?

Comment: Charles - your answer is improved now that you've changed it. Your original answer would've been giving 14 dates earlier than the start of the current month. I've removed my -1.

Comment: @Billy, this IS creating buckets from the 15th through the 14th of the next month.  It's just DESCRIBING THEM by a date of the first of the month...  i.e. any date from 15 Nov through 14 Dec will give you 1 Nov, any date from 15 Dec through 14 Jan will give you 1 Dec, etc...